# how to make code check if appium server timed out

Tags: java, android, mobile, automation, appium

my program runs into errors where the appium server hangs indefinitely while trying to find elements using the xpath identifier

i have added the desired capability to my appium test so that it times out after 60 seconds if no code is executed

```
cap.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 60);
```

requirements for my program include that it must reset if the appium server has timed out

but how would i make my program know that the server has timed out so that it can reset itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply catch **TimeoutException**. Try to find an element as below

```
try
{
MobileElement mobileElement= (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.id("ID"));
}
catch (TimeoutException e) {
// Do your stuff here
}
```

Appium java docs for [TimeoutException](http://appium.github.io/droiddriver/javadoc/io/appium/droiddriver/exceptions/TimeoutException.html)